# What all should be part of oracle package and what not

Tags: oracle

I have tables, seq, triggers, sp, types, oracle queues etc.

I want to know what should ideally form part of a package and what should be outside.
Can tables be part of package ?

the general practice followed ? and its benefits.

I understand the main idea of package acting like a library or a namespace.
And one benefit w.r.t managing in SQL IDE I see is that you can easily drop and recreate and easily view and manage thigns occuring under one package.

What others ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to [the Oracle documentation for packages](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/packages.htm#CIHIJECJ) and read the section called "What is a package?".  It starts off:

> A **package** is a schema object that groups logically related PL/SQL
>   types, variables, constants, subprograms, cursors, and exceptions. A
>   package is compiled and stored in the database, where many
>   applications can share its contents. You can think of a package as an
>   application.

It cannot include tables, triggers, sequence definitions etc.